# Is it possible for a human-habitable, rotating planet to have an encircling bridge of human-walkable matter that connects both poles?

Tags: geography

Imagine a strip of land that divided the world in two, by encircling the globe, connecting the poles.

I want this belt to form naturally and be a constant feature, at least for over 5000 years.

Any ideas on what could produce this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While plate tectonics could randomly throw up a belt of land in the formation you want, it would be difficult to develop due to the rotational energy of the planet attempting to bring the continents towards the equator. The configuration of the Earth's plates has ranged from singular supercontinents to the sorts of arrangements we see today. Before today, the continents were arranged like a bunch of islands (North and South America were not attached, and India was a separate entity from Asia, for example. It is projected that there will be something close to what you are looking for in +50MY.[image: -650 MY]
[image: -50MY]
[image: +50MY]

As for the time frame, continental plates move at the blinding speed of millimetres per year, so a configuration of the plates will remain stable for millions of years.

Answer (score 7):

Imagine a world which has coast shapes much like Earth, except that where we have oceans it has land and where we have land it has oceans. Ice stays ice. This world would have the band you're talking about, narrowing to less than 100 miles at the former Bering Strait and bulging to thousands of miles at the former Pacific and Atlantic.

Would the be human-habitable?

- The albedo will change. This could be balanced by a different orbit.
- There will be no currents like the Gulfstream to balance temperatures.
- The interiors of the large continents will be dry.
- The separate oceans will have separate lifeforms.

I don't think effects like these would make the world uninhabitable.

Comment: Makes sense. Even simpler: just imagine Argentina to stretch down to Antartica, and Canada to stretch up to north pole.

Comment: So, is this land formation able to form naturally, and remain stable for 5000+ years?

Comment: No--the south pole would be water, thus not walkable.  The idea is sound, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel "Ice stays ice" so Antarctica is still solid.

Comment: Much depends on if you pour all the original water back into the inverted world, or stop when the familiar coastlines appear. See [Inversia](http://www.worlddreambank.org/I/INV.HTM) and [Abyssia](http://www.worlddreambank.org/A/ABY.HTM) for a very detailed analysis of the (possible) climate and ecology.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done on earth with pontoon bridges, such as are seen by Seattle WA. There are a few possible routes. Through the new world, you would head south from the North Pole to Greenland, which has been used as a launching point for polar expeditions. Pontoon bridge to Canada. Walk the length of the North, Central, and South America using existing pathways and roads. When you get to Tierra del Fuego, you build another pontoon bridge to Antarctica.

A European route would take you by bridge to Norway, Finland or Russia, down existing roads to Africa, then another pontoon bridge to Antarctica.

While this is technically possible, it would be very expensive., and the pontoon bridges would block shipping routes.

Any other planet which had large areas of water could similarly be bridged with a series of floating bridges--but crossing these in a boat is a far more economic approach.

Comment: The one problem here is that pontoon bridges will have a hard time forming naturally (as the asked intended)! Although perhaps pumice or a related rock could do the trick. Anyway, what do you suggest making the bridges out of?

Comment: @HDE226868 "Anyway, what do you suggest making the bridges out of?"  -- Ice. North pole is kind of there (though less and less so), with a bit of glaciation in Patagonia you'd have the walkable route from South to North Pole. Not quite "land"  the question specified, but close enough.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Interesting thought, although I would be worried about 1) Currents and 2) Melting of the ice due to high equatorial temperatures.

Comment: @HDE226868 You do not need to worry - 1) Glaciation over Strait of Magellan will shut down the currents and 2) No need to keep the ice in equatorial regions, there is already perfectly walkable land (there are bridges over the Panama Canal)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Ah, never mind; I was thinking of a single continuous bridge.